# set multiple variables in batch from variables set in script python

Tags: python, batch-file, variables, set

In batch, I need to read a configuration file written in python that contains multiples variables that I need to set in the batch script !

For example:    (variable take are just example, values can be integer, path, ...)

config.py

```
import time, os
VERSION= "20160801"
PATH = os.getcwd()
...
```

script.bat

```
SET VERSION= need to get VERSION variable from config.py
SET PATH =  need to get PATH variable from config.py
```

I have found this solution :

```
%PYTHON_PATH% -c "import config;print config.VERSION" > output
set /p CURRENT_VERSION=<output
```

but it functions just to one variable and i need to set around 30 variables, there exist a method to do this faster without import the config.py each time please ?

Why can i make this :

```
%PYTHON_PATH% -c "import config;print config.VERSION;print config.PATH" > version,path
set CURRENT_VERSION=version
set PATH=path
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type config.py^|find "="') do set %%a
```

**BUT:**
`set` doesn't ignore spaces, so with your example, it will create a variable named `%path %` (which isn't *that* bad, because `%path%` is an essential system variable. Changing it will lead to unexpected behavour).

You really should tell phyton to write those lines without spaces... (and take care to not use variable names, that are essential to windows)

Comment: It doesn't execute the script python and just return the associate code, so for the variable TODAY it returns  " time.strftime("%Y%M%d  %H:%m:%S")"

Comment: how should it do that with the file content you have shown? If `config.py` is an executable which outputs what you showed, just delete the `type` command.